# Realtime File Sync solution for windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

When I develop web applications I'm frequently need to sync files from a working folder to external server or another folder. I like keeping my code separated from the web sever.

In open source world there is the eclipse with file sync that does the job pretty well.  Unfortunately I can't find any good replacement for Visual Studio.

I've only found two generic solutions: 
- Winscp which is pretty good but stucks when a file is locked and ask for confirmation. Which is quite annoying.
- DSynchronize which works pretty well (ie. doesn't ask questions) but doesn't have filters so I can't tell it not to sync my .svn files or web.conf :(.

Do you know any good way to achieve realtime synchronization in Visual Studio or windows?

I doens't have to have gui in fact I would love to see a command line solution like a powershell command that outputs modified files.

Comment: DSynchronize filters, see http://superuser.com/q/705685/205566

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6311983/22470

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using Mercurial (to skip the .svn files) and DSynchronize to sync files

Answer (score 0):

I would give a try to immortal classic - rsync. There is cygwin enabled implementation for Windows called cwrsync: http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650 . With proper configuration (potentially with some fine tuning with scripting as well) it will do perfectly.

If you would like to have bi directional synchronization, the Unison may be the answer:
[http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/)

If you are looking for something even fancier, you might give a try to one of distributed file systems available, like CODA (I'm afraid decent Windows systems aren't supported yet): http://www.coda.cs.cmu.edu or native DFS solution from Microsoft, however I'm afraid the set up is too hassling (if not impossible in your case) since it's targeted for enterprise solutions:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753479(WS.10).aspx

Of course DFS option probably won't support filtering you are interested in.

Comment: None of the utilities you mention are realtime. Are they?

Comment: Distributed files systems are supposed to operate realtime, but in practice the replication mechanism is always a subject of some scheduling/queuing hence in my opinion it's just a question if it's done internally or you have to set up it on your own. I believe rsync is lightweight enough to be run it in a schedule with fairly limited time delay using Windows Task Scheduler. You could even go a step further and trigger rsync task on certain event ("save" in Visual Studio?) rather by timer. The question is  if VS publishes appropriate event OOTB.