# Automated Synchronisation of server files and local files

Tags: synchronization, winscp

Is there any application that does a automated update of the server file and local file? WinSCP does the local to server update and uni directional. Is there any bidirectional application?

Comment: I really want to help you here but can you expand on your question a little bit so I can understand exactly what you are trying to do? I feel like I'm the one trying to answer all your questions with the winscp tag :X

Comment: I have a case where i need to sync the files that is updated from the server to the client. This is not possible with WinSCPs keep remote directory upto date. with synchronisation it cant be automated. Unless you run the command executables.

Comment: Use the sync to server functionality of WinSCP: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6311983/22470

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Winscp is bi direcional. I currently use this program to automate a directory of documents to 100+ computers. A simple batch file containing the commands found on this page:

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize

Below,is the batch file I use to accomplish a sync from an ftp server to a local directory, deleting any changes on the local side.The batch file also saves a XML log of all transfers.

```
@echo off
cd %programfiles(x86)%\winscp\
start /b winscp.exe /log="C:\Sync\logs\!M-!D-!Y@!T.xml" /xmlgroups /command "open   ftp://username:password@ftp.foo.com" "synchronize local -delete -criteria=size     ""C:\Users\jdoe\Documents\Synced Docs"" /
```

The parameter that you will want to play with is the "**synchronize local -delete -criteria=size**"

I have had this in place for about a year and it works great. Let me know if you have any questions.